# Django user permissions not showing in production

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, supervisord

I have a weird problem.  In production I can't see the user permissions list in Django admin and after opening the group edit page it shows nothing and page language transforms to another language.

I have some custom permission defined in app models.

What I have done:

1. Sync my local database with production database.
2. Setting default encoding in supervisor (I thought maybe if my app verbose name is a Unicode name so that's why it won't load)

I'm using Django version 1.7.

Update: It looks like the problem is from gunicorn or supervisord because it's working in direct runserver.

Comment: Too few infomation, I can make a guesd only: app not configured in the settings.

Comment: but its work lke a charm in local , the problem is just in production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was from os default encoding , I had some unicode permission names in my records and it's wont load and error happened .

so I just add this three line in my wsgi.py

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```